# Disabling user accounts in MediaWiki

Tags: php, mediawiki, user-accounts

I have a wiki family that has several thousand users that I need to manage. We do not have an elegant way of disabling any of the users that have left the program, in the past we have been able to change their passwords, but this is not a lasting solution for the future. I have investigated a couple different ways of disabling a user account, but I'm not sure which option to choose.

1. The [CentralAuth](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aCentralAuth) extension - This is pretty complicated to set up for a wiki family and is tied very closely to the wikipedia core development. I got as far as migrating my users into the centralauth global user table. This setup does not take into account table prefixes, which we use extensively. The special pages associated with the extension are all broken because of this.
2. IP Blocking - I can't use this since the multiple users may access the wiki from the same IP, at a work station or computer lab.
3. A hook on login - Could possibly use a hook (UserLoginComplete) when the user logs in, then log them out immediately based on a flag set in the database.
4. Shared Permissions - I took a look at a couple extensions that allow global permissions, but many of them are not stable or in beta, for example: [SharedUserRights](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSharedUserRights). The idea here is to create an 'inactive' permission and manage accounts globally with that permission group.

I'm open to ideas! Hopefully this all makes sense, thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "disabling"? Yes, revoking their `edit` (and `view`?) rights is the way to do it. Not sure how CentralAuth could help with that

Comment: By disabling I mean making the user have 'anonymous' rights, taking edit privileges away. We don't want to delete the account since the users may return. I was trying to get CentralAuth to work since it has 'hide account' and 'lock account from editing' options when editing using the global user manager page. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for the suggestions! I ended up using a global ipblocks table and [Extension:Lockout](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLockout) to block users from logging in, effectively disabling their accounts. I set up the shared tables and shared database for global users in my LocalSettings.php file:

```
 $wgSharedDB = 'up_commonusers';
 $wgSharedTables = array(  'user', 'user_groups', 'account_requests', 'account_credentials', 'ipblocks');
```

I plan on managing the blocked accounts based on username with this list: Special:BlockList. The drawback of this list is that it does not have the user's home wiki, so I added a 'ipb_user_home' column to the ipblocks table to use as reference later with this hook:

```
 $wgHooks['BlockIpComplete'][] = 'addHomeWikiData';

 function addHomeWikiData(&$block, &$user){
     $userId = $block->getTarget() instanceof User ? $block->getTarget()->getID() : 0;

     if($userId>0){
        $dbw = wfGetDB(DB_MASTER);
        $row = $dbw->selectRow('user', '*', array('user_id'=>$userId));
        $dbw->begin();
        $dbw->update('ipblocks', array('ipb_user_home'=>$row->user_home), array('ipb_user'=>$userId));
        $dbw->commit();
        return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

I will eventually write my own Block list table in the future that will use this info, but for now I have what I need.

So the workflow is pretty simple. I use the normal Special:Block page to block users. The blocked users are added to the global ipblocks table instead of the local one since we configured a SharedTable, it then adds their home wiki data with the hook. The Lockout extension uses a different hook on login that will detect if the user is blocked or not and throw an error message. The Error pops up and you can't log in.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely lock them out (disable logging in), use the [AbortLogin hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/AbortLogin) to check usernames against the blacklist. See [Extension:Lockout](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLockout) for an example.

If you want them to be able to log in but not edit, you can pobably use the [UserGetRights hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/UserGetRights) to strip edit rights from them.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with mediawiki [standard user rights handling](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aUser_rights)? Just give read/write access to a specific group and [remove a user from that group](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aSetting_user_groups_in_MediaWiki#Revoking_user.27s_privileges) when it is no longer relevant?

Comment: Those work well, but there is no easy way to globally manage user permissions. There is a user_groups table for each wiki in the wiki family, so I would have to change the permissions for each user on every wiki. We have a shared user table, but am not sure how to force each wiki to use the global user_groups table.

Comment: MediaWiki manual: "If a member has multiple groups, they get all of the permissions from each of the groups they are in. All users, including anonymous users, are in the '*' group; all registered users are in the 'user' group. In addition to the default groups, you can arbitrarily create new groups using the same array." I.E. Creating a "Disabled" group and removing rights from it does not disable the user because the user is automatically part of a user group that grants the removed permissions. "Standard user rights handling" seems insufficient as there is no UI to remove from 'users'.